# Oracle convert from utf-16 hex to utf-8 character

Tags: oracle, encoding, utf-8, plsql, utf-16

My database character set is AL32UTF8 and national character set AL16UTF16. I need to store in a table numeric values of some characters according to db character set and later on display a specific character using numeric value. I had some problems with understanding how this encoding works (differences between unistr, chr, ascii functions and so on), but eventually I found [website](https://bitbach.wordpress.com/2012/09/11/just-another-discussion-of-unicode-character-conversion-for-oracle/) where the following code was used:

```
chr(ascii(convert(unistr(hex), AL32UTF8)))
```

And it works fine when hex code is smaller than 1000 when I use for example:

```
chr(ascii(convert(unistr('\1555'), AL32UTF8)))
chr(ascii(convert(unistr('\1556'), AL32UTF8)))
```

it returns the same ascii value (`ascii(convert(unistr('\hex >= 1000'), AL32UTF8))`). Could anyone look at this and try to explain what's the reason? I really thought I understood how it works, but now I'm confused a bit.

Comment: What is your intention? Do you have real example of your requirement? Why do you like to store numbers (or hex code) instead of simple character?

Comment: [UNISTR(hex)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions204.htm) takes numbers up to `FFFF` directly (i.e. Unicode [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)), characters above have to be entered differently. However, I doubt you are really looking for this.

Comment: I need to use characters from 'extended ascii' and I cannot just copy & paste them. I believe there is a way to store unicode values and convert to characters

Comment: What is 'extended ascii'? And do you cannot copy&paste?

Comment: Actually in order to convert from AL32UTF8 to AL16UTF16 (or vice versa) you can simply use `TO_CHAR(N'yxz')`, resp. `TO_NCHAR('yxz')`